# Migrando proyecto viejo a una versión reciente de Android Studio 3.4.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio

amigos tengo un proyecto del año 2016 creado en android studio, y quiero migrarlo para la nueva version de android studio v3.4.2 que es la que estoy usando, este es el proyecto por si quieres chequear : [Proyecto](https://www.4shared.com/rar/uMWIbl8Tiq/Merl1nVision.html)

he tratado de hacerlo, para  hacerlo correr en una API 27, pero me genera este error:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

y este es el build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.epam.merl1n.info.privateblog.merl1nvision"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0"
    compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.0.0"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

como puedo hacer para migrarlo???

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que editar el build.gradle y debes tener algo como esto:

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
    }
```

Debes editar el que se encuentra en el directorio raíz del proyecto.
[Aquí](https://developer.android.com/studio/build?hl=es) puedes encontrar más información.

Comment: amigo se a que te refieres,  eso trate de hacer ayer, cuando  añadi google() me arrojo un error  que desconocia esa funcion

Comment: Si eso no funciona por que no creas un proyecto nuevo, y después solamente copias el código fuente que está en la carpeta src.

Comment: FrEqDe  revise y en el directorio del proyecto no esta esa carpeta..... si puedes revisa aqui esta e proyecto que estoy trabajando https://www.4shared.com/rar/uMWIbl8Tiq/Merl1nVision.html

Comment: FrEqDe  aplique lo que me recomendastes y funciono..... el sync compilo sin problemas, ahora cuando fui a generar el apk en Generate Signed Build/  APK me genero un error.

Comment: Tienes que especificar que error obtuviste, es importante.